# Redmine Gitosis installation: rake cannot find inifile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redmine

I successfully installed Redmine today. I tried to install the Gitosis plugin as described [here](http://www.x2on.de/2011/04/23/tutorial-redmine-with-git-and-gitosis-on-ubuntu-11-04/). When i run the command `sudo -u www-data X_DEBIAN_SITEID=default RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate:plugins` i get this error:

```
(in /var/www/lemusc.de/redmine/public_html)
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:9: warning: already      initialized constant RUBY
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/file_utils.rb:86: warning: already    initialized constant LN_SUPPORTED
Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- inifile

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

i installed inifile with `gem install inifile` as it is described in the tutorial, but it still occurs.

any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  got the answer from here: http://eric.lubow.org/2009/ruby/parsing-ini-files-with-ruby/

calling `$:.unshift( '/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/inifile-0.1.0/lib/' )` helped. I had to change it to the path were the inifile lib is

Answer (score 0):

While listing gems (`gem list`) I've noticed something like this:

```
Invalid gemspec in [/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/inifile-1.1.0.gemspec]: invalid date format in specification: "2012-02-28 00:00:00.000000000Z"
```

So I went to this spec file (`/var/lib/gems/1.8/specifications/inifile-1.1.0.gemspec`) and simply erased the line with the date.

After that, my redmine came back to live.